# using RestAPI and jquery, we want to create term, by setting the values of description and available for tagging

Tags: rest, managed-metadata

In Sharepoint hosted app, using RestAPI and jquery, we want to create term, by setting the values of description and available for tagging. How will we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy API is not supported via REST service but you could consider to create a term via JSOM API in SharePoint-hosted app as demonstrated below:

```
var sp_files = [
    'SP.Runtime.js', 
    'SP.js', 
    'SP.Taxonomy.js'
];

var layoutsPath = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
$.getMultiScripts(sp_files, layoutsPath).done(function() {

     var termSetId = 'cb59f0f1-df29-4586-883d-b5f860d89c9f';
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
     var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore(); //retrieve default Term Store
     var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);

     //create Term
     var termGuid = SP.Guid.newGuid();
     var termName = "News";
     var newTerm = termSet.createTerm(termName, 1033, termGuid.toString());
     newTerm.setDescription('News term',1033);
     ctx.load(newTerm);
     $.executeQueryPromise(ctx,newTerm)
     .then(function(term){
            console.log("Term has been created");
          },logError);
});


function logError(error){
    console.log(error.get_message());
}
```

where

```
//from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method
$.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {
    var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
        return $.getScript( (path||"") + scr );
    });

    _arr.push($.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    }));
    return $.when.apply($, _arr);
}    




$.executeQueryPromise = function(ctx, result) {
    result = result || {};
    var d = $.Deferred();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
         d.resolve(result);
    }, function (sender, args) {
         d.reject(args);
    });
    return d.promise();
}
```